# How to resize cell height and the row height in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that display a program name and the DJ name. For some programmes, there are no any DJs. So I created a custom `UITableViewCell` by putting 2 `UILabels`. Middle of the `UITableViewCell` displays the programme name and bottom `UILabel` displays the DJ name. To display both programme and the DJ name I have to set the `cell size` and `UITableViewCell` size as `147`. But when DJ is not available I want to hide that bottom label and resize the cell and row height to 70. so how should I do this ?

I am checking if this DJ is `null` or not inside my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. 
How I can resize the cell, and row height ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 100's of answers already available

Comment: Are you getting DJ's from web service?

Comment: I would recommend @Anoop Vaidya's method as well. But generally I suggest to use two use two different prototype cells for displaying different content. You can set the height property for each prototype cell in interface builder and if I'm not mistaken you might even get the rest (setting the appropriate row height) "for free".

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the following delegate:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath {
      if(...){
          return 147.0f; //or whatever
      }
      else{
          return 70.f;
     }
}
```

Comment: dont want to set the size for cell seprately?

Answer (score 0):

Add NSIndexPath below @implementation

```
NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath;
```

Add Both of these methods.

```
// And in the implementation file:
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath;

    // Forces the table view to call heightForRowAtIndexPath
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Note: Some operations like calling [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
    // will call heightForRow and thus create a stack overflow
    if(selectedCellIndexPath != nil
       && [selectedCellIndexPath compare:indexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
        return 338;

    return 64;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 types of cell. With height of 147 and 70 pixels.

1) As Anoop Vaidya said you should set cell height by checking "DJ is null or not".

2) To avoid reusing wrong cell template, you should use 2 types of cellIdentifier:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *CellIdentifier = nil;
if (check DJ is nil or not) {
    CellIdentifier = @"CellWithHeight_147";
} else {
    CellIdentifier = @"CellWithHeight_70";
}

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
...
return cell;
```

}